# Need to copy 150+ files from different network folders into one local folder

Tags: powershell

Have a powershell question. I will break it down into bulleted points;

1. Need to copy 150+ files from remote locations within a network to my local machine. They are all small and typically txt, doc or docx files.
2. I have all of the file paths saved to a txt file that I would like to use as an input file.
3. I have access to all of the remote folders and do not require any authentication.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the simplest would seem to be to load the text file [Get-Content], iterate thru the list [foreach ($Thing in $Collection)], and copy the files [Copy-Item].

Comment: Thanks! I got the script working, now I am having issues with copying over files of the same name. Is there any way to append a 1 or something to the file name?

This is what I'm running;


Get-Content x:\paths.txt | Foreach-Object { copy-item -Path $_ -Destination "x:\files\"}

Comment: the easiest way to version same-named files is to postfix the current date & time. as long as the granularity is fine enuf, you won't have any name collisions. so, test for "already there", add the date formatted with `yyyy-Mm-dd_HH-mm-ss` to the .BaseName, and then copy/move the file at will. ///// heck, you can even skip the "is it there" test and just rename all the files ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant code I've written but it does the job:

```
$destination = "x:\files\"
Get-Content "paths.txt" | foreach {
    Get-ChildItem $_\* | foreach {
        $suffix = 0
        do {
            if ($suffix -eq 0) {$name = $_.Name}
            else {$name = $_.BaseName + "_" + $suffix + $_.Extension}
            $suffix++
        }
        until(-not(Test-Path (Join-Path $destination $name)))

        Copy-Item $_.FullName (Join-Path $destination $name)
    }
}
```

Comment: I've formatted your answer and also removed the aliases so it's easier to understand :)

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!